# Power BI report not getting published(Error 404)

Tags: sql-server, http-status-code-404, powerbi

I made a report using Sql Server, in which i used dax.
I could publish the report till the day before but today i m getting error only in that file when i publish the report
Error Occured are " An Error occured while  attempting to publish 'Reportname' ,The remote server returned an error:(404) not found".
I tried deleting some table  and report of that file but i  still could not publish ,then i create multiple raplica of that report but still none of it worked.
On the otherhand the backup which i took 2 days before is being published properly.
 Please help !!
Thanks in adv!!

Comment: Did you import data into your report, or used DirectQuery?

Comment: Was the report in use by others when you tried to republish it?  PowerBI does still suffer occasional service outages in parts of its architecture. Does it work today?

Comment: I had import data for that report @user5226582

Comment: I had shared the report to other people but i m sure that  no one was using it..anyways I tried publishing it again and again but i couldn't. And it still its not working till today.@ user3275601

Comment: Finally I decided to make replica of it.